# 2D Graphical Editing Framework for PowerPoint or Visio style editing (.NET Prefered)?

Tags: .net, graphics, editor

Is there a good 2D Graphical Editing Framework for PowerPoint or Visio style editing?  A .NET solution is prefered for our application.  In our case, a lightweight solution is preferable to a heavyweight solution.  We aren't looking for the full range of features found in PowerPoint or Visio - just the basics.